# How to position the Glypicon on the left of the bootstrap button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This code position the left-arrow on the right the text. I prefer to position the glyphicon on the left.

```
<button class="btn primary btn-lg" style="width:100%" >
    This way <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" style="align:left"></span>
</button>
```

Thank for you help

Comment: First put icon then text. `<button class="btn primary btn-lg" style="width:100%" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left style="align:left" "></span> This way</button>`

Comment: Thank but it does not work

Comment: see @hankd123's JSFiddle

Comment: Sorry, it works. I see only one part of your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` is what displays the Glyphicon. Put the `span` first prior to the text and it will be positioned to the left like so:

```
<button class="btn primary btn-lg" style="width:100%" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left style="align:left" "></span>
    This way
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place the `span` before the text. The "align" property is unnecessary (and as pointed out, not a thing :) ).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> This Way
</button>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v49kj8sw/

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples

Comment: Thanks Hankd. It works well. I am a little bit ashame as it is so obvious when  i read the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `width:100%` is useless in bootstrap. You should use `col-lg-12`, `col-md-12`, `col-sd-12` or `col-xs-12` which put a 100% width to the element.

Secondly, to put the icon on the left, you have to put the `span` tag first in the button like this:

```
<button class="btn primary btn-lg col-lg-12"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left style="align:left" "></span> This way</button>
```

Comment: thank  you for the advice. I put the bootstrap button in a  cell of the table. This table is in modal windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no property named align in css. use `text-align` for inline elements. or `float` left/right for the element and `overflow:hidden` for the parent / clearfix hack , or [`display:flex`](http://codepen.io/osublake/pen/dMLQJr) with `justify-content: flext-start`.